# String pattern matching on case clause

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

With for example this tuple:

```
{:error,
 "Timeout error: {:timeout, {:gen_server, :call, [#PID<0.12345.0>"]}}"}
```

Is it possble to do something similar to this?

```
case result do
  {:ok, result} -> result
  {:error, msg =~ "Timeout"} -> "Timeout error"
  {:error, _msg} -> "Another different error"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't match a substring at arbitrary index in patterns, but in this case, since the string *starts* with `Timeout`, you can do this:

```
case result do
  {:ok, result} -> result
  {:error, "Timeout" <> _} -> "Timeout error"
  {:error, _msg} -> "Another different error"
end
```